# Custom function wordpress php

Tags: functions

I need develop a function which will check the parameter in the url if the parameter is there need to write the functions inside.  the function should check the example.com/login/?tokenrequest=xyz.url/asd.pdf if token request parameter is there need to add token and send to third party url the function should alwarys work throught out the site

Comment: can you rephrase/reword your question? It's not easy to understand in english, and there's no information about the function or what you are trying to do that needs this

Answer (score 0):

You must be thinking something like this:

In this URL: https://myawesomewebsite.com/page?custom_id=456

```
function check_parameter_in_url() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['custom_id'] ) {
        //do something
    }
}
```